# Which files of the go ethreum source code need to be changed to add a new type of transaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, golang

I need to update the source code of go ethereum so it can handle a new type of transaction. This new transaction will have a new field. Which directories and files of project would need to be updated for this purpose?